# conditional expectation solution to exercise

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, conditional-expectation

I have the following probabilities:
$$\begin{matrix}0.11&0.04&0.19\\0.19&0.12&0.19\\0.09&0.07&0\\\end{matrix}$$

With $x$ random variables horizontally, and $y$ random variables vertically. starting from $x = 0, 1, 2$ and $y = 0, 1, 2$.

I have to calculate $E(X|Y)$. I know that $p_{X|Y}(x|y) = \frac{P(X=x \space \cap \space Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}$ where $P(Y=y)$ is the marginal density for the discrete joint distribution.

We have the following:
$$\begin{align} \sum_{i=0}^3P_{X|Y}(X=i|Y=0) &= \frac{0.11}{0.34}+\frac{0.04}{0.34} +\frac{0.19}{0.34} \\ \sum_{i=0}^3P_{X|Y}(X=i|Y=1) &= \frac{0.19}{0.50}+\frac{0.12}{0.50} +\frac{0.19}{0.50} \\ \sum_{i=0}^3P_{X|Y}(X=i|Y=2) &= \frac{0.09}{0.16}+\frac{0.07}{0.16} +\frac{0}{0.16}\end{align}$$

$$E(X|Y) = \sum_{i=0}^3x_iP_{X|Y}(X=i|Y=y) \\ = 0 \cdot \left(\frac{0.11}{0.34}+ \frac{0.19}{0.50} + \frac{0.09}{0.34} \right)+1 \cdot \left(\frac{0.04}{0.34}+ \frac{0.12}{0.50} + \frac{0.07}{0.16} \right)+2 \cdot \left(\frac{0.19}{0.34}+ \frac{0.19}{0.50} + \frac{0}{0.16} \right)=2.67$$

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: Kindly repost your query - I cannot read your calculations on conditional probability results..

Comment: @Dr.Sundar updated

Comment: In the discrete bivariate distribution, conditional expectation of X can be calculated for a fixed value of $Y$ - let us say, $Y = 0$ or $Y = 1$ or $Y = 2$. I don't understand how you can find E(X | Y)..

Comment: The general procedure is this: Fix a value of $Y$, let us say - $Y = y_i$. Then we calculate the marginal density of $X$ for this fixed value of $Y$ ; that is; $f_{X | Y}(x | Y = y_i)$, and then calculate $E_{X | Y}(X | Y = y_i)$. It is important that we fix some value of $Y$ in this calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E[X|Y]$ is a function of $Y$.
\begin{align}
E[X|Y=0] &= 0\cdot \frac{0.11}{0.34} + \frac{0.04}{0.34} + 2\cdot \frac{0.19}{0.34}\\
E[X|Y=1] &= 0\cdot \frac{0.19}{0.50}+ \frac{0.12}{0.50} + 2\cdot \frac{0.19}{0.50}
\end{align}

I am leaving the evaluation of $E[X|Y=2]$ to you. If you insist you can use indicator variable to combine the formula.

Comment: Thank you! this makes what Dr.Sundar said much clearer

Comment: An additional question; How would I calculate $E(E(X|Y))$ in this case?

Comment: that would be equal to $E[X]$ by the law of total expectation.

Comment: Yes - given the marginal pmf's for x are given as $P(X=0) = 0.39, P(X=1) = 0.23, P(X=2) = 0.38$ then $E(X) = 0 \cdot 0.39 + 1 \cdot 0.23 + 2 \cdot 0.38 = 0.99$. How do I get $E(E(X|Y)) = 0.99$? I'm confused on how to proceed given that we have calculated for all values of Y.

Comment: I have tried something like $E[E(X|Y)]=\sum_{x=0}^2 xE(X|Y) = 1 \cdot (\frac{0.12}{0.50} + 2\cdot \frac{0.19}{0.50}) + 2 \cdot \frac{0.19}{0.50}$

Comment: $E[E(X|Y)]=\sum_y Pr(Y=y)E[X|Y=y]$